# QNetworkReply returning empty response if HTTP response type is 201 CREATED

Tags: c++, qt, http, http-headers

I'm using Qt to POST some data to a server (which I have control over). When the reply is finished, the response is exactly as I expect if I set the HTTP status to 200 OK, but if I change it on the server to 201 CREATED (as it should be), then calling `reply->readAll()` returns an empty byte array.

Testing this in a REST client with exactly the same parameters, URL, and data gives me the reply I'm expecting, so I know this is not a problem with the server. Is this a bug in Qt, or is it intentional?

I'm making the request as follows:

```
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
        reply->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        emit uploadCompleted(QString(reply->readAll()));
        reply->close();
    }else{
        emit uploadFailed("Server returned " + QString::number(statusCode).append(" ") + QString(reply->error()));
        reply->close();
    }
    toUpload.close();
    reply->deleteLater();
```

If the status is 200, the `emit uploadCompleted` call gives me the correct data. However, if the status is 201, I get nothing at all, just an empty `QByteArray`.

The response is of type `text/plain` and just contains a short, single line of text about 50 characters in length or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling `reply->open` before trying to call `readAll()`. For whatever reason, if you open it before reading when the status is 200, you encounter no issues. But if you do so when the status is 201 (or perhaps other values, I haven't tested), the read operation fails.